# jQuery Select Second child of First Instance of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can jQuery be used to select `Bar`, which is the second child of the first `p` element within `div.page`?

Thank you!

```
<div class="page">
    <h4>Hello</h4>
    <p>
        <b>Foo</b>
        Bar
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Hello</b>
        World
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: `Bar` isn't child of `p`. It is text in `p`.

Comment: put `Bar` into a html tag such as `<b>`, `<span>`, ... to make it becomes child of `<p>` and then you can use jQuery to select `Bar`

Comment: `var barElement = $('.page p:nth-child(1)')`

Comment: @Desperado that will select the `p` element, not `Bar` like OP has asked

Comment: @wmash we cannot select the Bar because he didn't enclose it with a container like `span`. If im going to use this. `$('.page p:nth-child(1)').html()` `<b>` tag will be included

Comment: I cant control the HTML of the page, so I can't add the `span`

Comment: @Nyxynyx try this `var barElement = $('.page p:first-of-type');
console.log(barElement.html().replace('<b>Foo</b>', ''));`

Comment: @Desperado The code in your latest comment is the only one that appears to work so far!

Comment: can I add it as an answer? :3

Comment: @Nyxynyx Please mark on of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mohammed commented, Bar is not an element, it's the value of the first child. To select the first child p element under .page you can use `$('.page p:first-child')` to get the first child or `$('.page p:nth-of-type(1)')` where you can replace 1 with the index of the child you want. If you want to get 'Bar', use val() e.g. `$('.page p:first-child').val()`

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to finding first `p` element and use [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) property to getting sibling of `b` element.

```js
var bar = $(".page > p:first > b")[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim();
console.log(bar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
    <h4>Hello</h4>
    <p>
        <b>Foo</b>
        Bar
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Hello</b>
        World
    </p>
</div>
```

Also you can copy element and remove childs of `p` of copied element, then get text of it.

```
var bar = $('.page > p:first').clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello Friend use this code it will give you foo.......
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var foo = jQuery(".page").find('p b:eq(0)').text();
  alert(foo);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
    <h4>Hello</h4>
    <p>
        <b>Foo</b>
        Bar
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>Hello</b>
        World
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Question is about finding `Bar` but your answer trying to get `Foo`

Answer (score -1):

You can pass an index (1 in your case) as an argument to the nth-child function of jQuery.

```
$(".page:nth-child(1)");
```

Alternatively you can also use first-child

```
$(".page:first-child");
```